# Scrape College Football team recruiting rankings page

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

So I have been able to scrape the first 50 teams in the [team rankings webpage from 247sports](https://247sports.com/Season/2022-Football/CompositeTeamRankings/).

I was able to get the following results:

```
    index   Rank    Team    Total Recruits  Average Rating  Total Rating
0   0   1   Ohio State  17  94.35   286.75
1   10  11  Alabama 10  94.16   210.61
2   8   9   Georgia 11  93.38   219.60
3   31  32  Clemson 8   92.02   161.74
4   3   4   LSU 14  91.92   240.57
5   4   5   Oklahoma    13  91.81   229.03
6   22  23  USC 9   91.60   174.69
7   11  12  Texas A&M   11  91.59   203.03
8   1   2   Notre Dame  18  91.01   250.35
9   2   3   Penn State  18  90.04   243.95
10  6   7   Texas   14  90.04   222.03
11  14  15  Missouri    12  89.94   196.37
12  7   8   Oregon  15  89.91   220.66
13  5   6   Florida State   15  89.88   224.51
14  25  26  Florida 10  89.15   167.89
15  37  38  North Carolina  9   88.94   152.79
16  9   10  Michigan    16  88.76   216.07
17  33  34  UCLA    10  88.49   160.00
18  23  24  Kentucky    11  88.46   173.12
19  12  13  Rutgers 14  88.44   198.56
20  19  20  Indiana 12  88.41   181.20
21  49  50  Washington  8   88.21   132.55
22  20  21  Oklahoma State  13  88.18   177.91
23  43  44  Ole Miss    10  87.80   143.35
24  44  45  California  9   87.78   141.80
25  17  18  Arkansas    15  87.75   188.64
26  16  17  South Carolina  15  87.61   190.84
27  32  33  Georgia Tech    11  87.30   161.33
28  35  36  Tennessee   11  87.25   157.77
29  39  40  NC State    11  87.18   150.18
30  46  47  SMU 9   87.08   138.50
31  36  37  Wisconsin   11  87.00   157.55
32  21  22  Mississippi State   15  86.96   177.33
33  24  25  West Virginia   13  86.78   171.72
34  30  31  Northwestern    14  86.76   162.66
35  40  41  Maryland    12  86.31   149.77
36  15  16  Virginia Tech   18  86.23   191.06
37  18  19  Baylor  19  85.90   184.68
38  13  14  Boston College  22  85.88   197.15
39  26  27  Michigan State  14  85.85   167.60
40  29  30  Cincinnati  14  85.68   164.90
41  34  35  Minnesota   13  85.55   159.35
42  28  29  Iowa State  14  85.54   166.50
43  48  49  Virginia    10  85.39   133.93
44  45  46  Arizona 11  85.27   140.90
45  41  42  Pittsburgh  12  85.10   147.58
46  47  48  Duke    13  85.02   137.40
47  27  28  Vanderbilt  16  85.01   166.77
48  38  39  Purdue  13  84.83   152.55
49  42  43  Illinois    13  84.15   143.86
```

From the following script:

```
year = '2022'

url = 'https://247sports.com/Season/' + str(year) + '-Football/CompositeTeamRankings/'
print(url)
# Add the `user-agent` otherwise we will get blocked when sending the request
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36"}

response = requests.get(url, headers = headers).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
data = []

for tag in soup.find_all("li", class_="rankings-page__list-item"):  
    rank = tag.find('div',{'class':'primary'}).text.strip()
    team = tag.find('div',{'class':'team'}).find('a').text.strip()
    total_recruits = tag.find('div',{'class':'total'}).find('a').text.split(' ')[0].strip()
    # five_stars = tag.find('div',{'class':'gold'}).text.strip()
    # four_stars = tag.find('div',{'class':'gold'}).text.strip()
    # three_stars = tag.find('div',{'class':'metrics'}).text.strip()
    avg_rating = tag.find('div',{'class':'avg'}).text.strip()
    total_rating = tag.find('div',{'class':'points'}).text.strip()

    data.append(
        {
            "Rank": rank,
            "Team": team,
            "Total Recruits": total_recruits,
#             "Five-Star Recruits": five_stars,
#             "Four-Star Recruits": four_stars,
#             "Three-Star Recruits": three_stars,
            "Average Rating": avg_rating,
            "Total Rating": total_rating
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df[['Rank', 'Total Recruits', 'Average Rating', 'Total Rating']] = df[['Rank', 'Total Recruits', 'Average Rating', 'Total Rating']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

df.sort_values('Average Rating', ascending = False).reset_index()
# soup
```

However, I would like to achieve three things.

1. I would like to grab the data from the "5-stars", "4-stars", "3-stars" columns in the webpage.
2. I would like to not just get the first 50 schools, but also tell the webpage to click "load more" enough times so that I can get the table with ALL schools in it.
3. I want to not only get the 2022 team rankings, but every team ranking that 247sports has to offer (2000 through 2024).

I tried to give it a go with this one script, but I constantly get the top-50 schools being outputted in one loop in the "print(row) portion" of the code.

```
print(datetime.datetime.now().time())

# years = ['2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', 
#          '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009',
#          '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', 
#          '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019',
#          '2020', '2021', '2022', '2023']

years = ['2022']

rows = []
page_totals = []
# recruits_final = []

for year in years:
  url = 'https://247sports.com/Season/' + str(year) + '-Football/CompositeTeamRankings/'
  print(url)
  headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Mobile Safari/537.36'}


  page = 0

  while True:
      page +=1 
      
      payload = {'Page': '%s' %page}
      response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
      tags = soup.find_all('li',{'class':'rankings-page__list-item'})
  
      if len(tags) == 0:
          print('Page: %s' %page)
          page_totals.append(page)
          break
  
      continue_loop = True
  
      while continue_loop == True:
          for tag in tags:
              if tag.text.strip() == 'Load More':
                  continue_loop = False
                  continue
                
              # primary_rank = tag.find('div',{'class':'rank-column'}).find('div',{'class':'primary'}).text.strip()
             
              # try:
              #     other_rank = tag.find('div',{'class':'rank-column'}).find('div',{'class':'other'}).text.strip()
              # except:
              #     other_rank = ''

              rank = tag.find('div',{'class':'primary'}).text.strip()
              team = tag.find('div',{'class':'team'}).find('a').text.strip()
              total_recruits = tag.find('div',{'class':'total'}).find('a').text.split(' ')[0].strip()
              # five_stars = tag.find('div',{'class':'gold'}).text.strip()
              # four_stars = tag.find('div',{'class':'gold'}).text.strip()
              # three_stars = tag.find('div',{'class':'metrics'}).text.strip()
              avg_rating = tag.find('div',{'class':'avg'}).text.strip()
              total_rating = tag.find('div',{'class':'points'}).text.strip()
              
              try:
                  team = athlete.find('div',{'class':'status'}).find('img')['title']
              except:
                  team = ''
              
              row = {'Rank': rank,
                    'Team': team,
                    'Total Recruits': total_recruits,
                    'Average Rating': avg_rating,
                    'Total Rating': total_rating,
                    'Year': year}

              print(row)
              
              rows.append(row)
              
              recruits = pd.DataFrame(rows)

print(datetime.datetime.now().time())
```

Any assistance on this is truly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A common way to scrape data from websites containing content loaded using javascript (which is the case for the "more" button) is using selenium, which lets you control a browser programmatically. A pretty good introduction can be found [here](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can extract the year ranges from the dropdown with `BeautifulSoup` (no need to click the button, as the dropdown is already on the page), and then navigate to each link with `selenium`, using the latter to interact with the "load more" toggle, and then finally scraping the resulting tables:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
import time, urllib.parse, re
d = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver')
d.get((url:='https://247sports.com/Season/2022-Football/CompositeTeamRankings/'))
result = {}
for i in soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').select('.rankings-page__header-nav > .rankings-page__nav-block .flyout_cmp.year.tooltip li a'):
   if (y:=int(i.get_text(strip=True))) > 1999: 
      d.get(urllib.parse.urljoin(url, i['href']))
      while d.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('a[data-js="showmore"]') != null"""):
         d.execute_script("""document.querySelector('a[data-js="showmore"]').click()""")
         time.sleep(1)
      result[y] = [{"Rank":i.select_one('div.wrapper .rank-column .other').get_text(strip=True),
           "Team":i.select_one('.team').get_text(strip=True),
           "Total":i.select_one('.total').get_text(strip=True).split()[0],
           "5-Stars":i.select_one('.star-commits-list li:nth-of-type(1) div').get_text(strip=True),
           "4-Stars":i.select_one('.star-commits-list li:nth-of-type(2) div').get_text(strip=True),
           "3-Stars":i.select_one('.star-commits-list li:nth-of-type(3) div').get_text(strip=True),
           "Ave":i.select_one('.avg').get_text(strip=True),
           "Points":i.select_one('.points').get_text(strip=True),
        }
        for i in soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').select("""ul[data-js="rankings-list"].rankings-page__list li.rankings-page__list-item""")]
```

`result` stores all the team rankings for a given year, 2000-2024 (`list(result)` produces `[2024, 2023, 2022, 2021, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000]`). To convert the results to a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Year':a, **i} for a, b in result.items() for i in b])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      Year Rank            Team Total 5-Stars 4-Stars 3-Stars    Ave Points
0     2024  N/A            Iowa     1       0       0       0   0.00   0.00
1     2024  N/A   Florida State     3       0       0       0   0.00   0.00
2     2024  N/A             BYU     1       0       0       0   0.00   0.00
3     2023    1         Georgia     4       0       4       0  93.86  93.65
4     2023    3      Notre Dame     2       1       1       0  95.98  51.82
...    ...  ...             ...   ...     ...     ...     ...    ...    ...
3543  2000  N/A        NC State    18       0       0       0  70.00   0.00
3544  2000  N/A  Colorado State    14       0       0       0  70.00   0.00
3545  2000  N/A          Oregon    27       0       0       0  70.00   0.00
3546  2000  N/A      California    25       0       0       0  70.00   0.00
3547  2000  N/A      Texas Tech    20       0       0       0  70.00   0.00

[3548 rows x 9 columns]
```

Edit: instead of using `selenium`, you can send requests to the API endpoints that the site uses to retrieve and display the ranking data:

```
import requests, pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
def extract_rankings(source):
   return [{"Rank":i.select_one('div.wrapper .rank-column .other').get_text(strip=True),
       "Team":i.select_one('.team').get_text(strip=True),
       "Total":i.select_one('.total').get_text(strip=True).split()[0],
       "5-Stars":i.select_one('.star-commits-list li:nth-of-type(1) div').get_text(strip=True),
       "4-Stars":i.select_one('.star-commits-list li:nth-of-type(2) div').get_text(strip=True),
       "3-Stars":i.select_one('.star-commits-list li:nth-of-type(3) div').get_text(strip=True),
       "Ave":i.select_one('.avg').get_text(strip=True),
       "Points":i.select_one('.points').get_text(strip=True),
    }
    for i in soup(source, 'html.parser').select("""li.rankings-page__list-item""")]

def year_rankings(year):
   page, results = 1, []
   vals = extract_rankings(requests.get(f'https://247sports.com/Season/{year}-Football/CompositeTeamRankings/?ViewPath=~%2FViews%2FSkyNet%2FInstitutionRanking%2F_SimpleSetForSeason.ascx&Page={page}', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Mobile Safari/537.36'}).text)
   while vals:
      results.extend(vals)
      page += 1
      vals = extract_rankings(requests.get(f'https://247sports.com/Season/{year}-Football/CompositeTeamRankings/?ViewPath=~%2FViews%2FSkyNet%2FInstitutionRanking%2F_SimpleSetForSeason.ascx&Page={page}', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Mobile Safari/537.36'}).text)
   return results

results = {y:year_rankings(y) for y in range(2000, 2025)}
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Year':a, **i} for a, b in results.items() for i in b])
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sending this to me. However, I should have brought up that I am trying to do this in Google colab and I got this error when testing it out. "
WebDriverException: Message: 'C:\path\to\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home"

Comment: @BLuta In my answer, `'path/to/chromedriver'` is simply a place holder. In your copy of the code above, replace `'path/to/chromedriver'` to with the real path to your Chromedriver executable

Comment: I do understand that. What I meant to say was even after replacing 'path/to/chromedriver' with my file path, it generated this error message.

Comment: @BLuta Ah, I see. There are a few things you can do: first, make sure you are providing the full path to the executable. Second, try moving the executable to the directory that also contains the Python script. This way, you can just do `d = webdriver.Chrome()`. Lastly, you can explicitly pass the path to `Chrome` by parameter assignment: `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path/to/chromedriver')`

Comment: @BLuta Please see my recent edit, as I updated my solution to include a `requests`-only approach

Comment: I feel optimistic about your edit. However, I received a syntax error in the beginning of the while loop for year_rankings (or line 17). I even removed the ":" sign on my end and turned the headers portion of the line into its separate equation beforehand and the script is still generating the same error message.

Comment: @BLuta `:=` is an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), available in Python versions >= 3.8. I edited `year_rankings` to support versions < 3.8.

Comment: Works for me!!!! Thank you so much for everything. I know that must have taken loads of work.

Comment: @BLuta Glad to help! Please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my solution if it helped you.